# ng-model is not being exposed outside of directive

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular accordion directive in a form. Unfortunately, the model inside the input field value could not be exposed or display outside of the directive. Not really sure which part is wrong.

Fiddler link:[Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/rLksvezd/)
Html

```
<body ng-app="btst">
     <h3>BootStrap Accordion Directives</h3>
<form>
    <pre>{{ form | json }}</pre> <!-- Not Working -->
    <btst-accordion>
        <btst-pane title="<b>First</b> Pane">
            <pre>{{ form | json }}</pre> <!-- Working -->
            Text: <input type="text" ng-model="form.textInput1"><br>
            Date: <input type="date" ng-model="form.dateInput1">
        </btst-pane>
        <btst-pane title="<b>Second</b> Pane">
            <pre>{{ form | json }}</pre> <!-- Working -->
            Text: <input type="text" ng-model="form.textInput2"><br>
            Number: <input type="date" ng-model="form.numberInput2">
        </btst-pane>
    </btst-accordion>

</form>
</body>
```

Directive

```
angular.module("btst", []).
directive("btstAccordion", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        template:
            "<div class='accordion' ng-transclude></div>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            // give this element a unique id
            var id = element.attr("id");
            if (!id) {
                id = "btst-acc" + scope.$id;
                element.attr("id", id);
            }

            // set data-parent on accordion-toggle elements
            var arr = element.find(".accordion-toggle");
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                $(arr[i]).attr("data-parent", "#" + id);
                $(arr[i]).attr("href", "#" + id + "collapse" + i);
            }
            arr = element.find(".accordion-body");
            $(arr[0]).addClass("in"); // expand first pane
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                $(arr[i]).attr("id", id + "collapse" + i);
            }
        },
        controller: function () {}
    };
}).
directive('btstPane', function () {
    return {
        require: "^btstAccordion",
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            title: "@",
            category: "=",
            order: "="
        },
        template:
            "<div class='accordion-group' >" +
            "  <div class='accordion-heading'>" +
            "    <a class='accordion-toggle' data-toggle='collapse'> {{category.name}} - </a>" +

            "  </div>" +
            "<div class='accordion-body collapse'>" +
            "  <div class='accordion-inner' ng-transclude></div>" +
            "  </div>" +
            "</div>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch("title", function () {
                // NOTE: this requires jQuery (jQLite won't do html)
                var hdr = element.find(".accordion-toggle");
                hdr.html(scope.title);
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: where do you define the `form` object?

Comment: @Ozrix where should I define it? I am expecting it to be auto populated once i fill in the value inside any of the input but it did not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues. First, you have to define the `form` object on the scope. Since you want to see it outside of the `btstAccordion` directive (see the `<pre>` element), you have to define it in a separate controller:

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.form = {};
}
```

and then use that controller in your HTML:

```
<form ng-controller="myCtrl">
```

This will make `<pre>{{ form | json }}</pre>` behave like you expect it to.

Next, you're isolating the scope on your `btstAccordion` directive, which means that the scope *outside* of the directive isn't visible *inside* the directive:

```
directive("btstAccordion", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {}, // <= isolated scope
```

You can either

1. remove the isolate scope
2. pass the `scope.form` object as a parameter to the directive

Demo of first approach http://jsfiddle.net/rLksvezd/4/

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I would like to use the second approach, as i would like to have isolated scope for btstAccordion for further configuration. Could you make a demo on second approach as well?

Comment: Notice that `btstAccordion` now has `scope: { form: "=" }` and in the HTML `<btst-accordion form="form">`, referencing `$scope.form`. That's how you propagate stuff into isolated scopes. If you open up your dev tools, you can see that as you type, the directive outputs the values in the console